# How to route only specific paths, else default/static files

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I've a CMS running as an ASP.NET Core MVC application, and I want that:

1. For `/api/` (or `/api/*`) and/or `/admin/`  (or `/admin/*`) it intercepts the link and correctly route using its MVC controller
2. Else, use static file (where I have `index.html` managed by a `vue.js` app, and its internal route).

Basic usage: if I type `/admin`, run the ASP.NET Core MVC application, if I type `/` (or whatever else, like `/pages/text`), call the `index.html` where `vuejs` routing will act.

How can I do it?

Tried this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseDefaultFiles(); // load index.html as default page
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseOrchardCore();
}
```

But it works only with `/`, `/api/*` and `/admin/*`. If I type `/pages/text`, it triggers the ASP.NET Core MVC controller and obviously return error (not the `vuejs app` routing).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a middleware that will handles all 404 responses and then overrides the path of your request:

```cs
public class ReturnDefaultMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ReturnDefaultMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next(context);
        
        // If controller was found, return the actual response
        if(context.Response.HasStarted || context.Response.StatusCode != (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            return;

        // Rewrite the request to request index.html
        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
        
        // Rerun the rest of the request pipeline
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

This will execute your request pipeline as usual. If the pipeline responds with 404 because not controller was found that can handle the route, the request will be overridden.
By running `await _next(context)` again, the whole pipeline will be processed again but for the new `index.html` route.

Simply add the new middleware befor running anything else:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    // Add custom middleware here
    app.UseMiddleware<ReturnDefaultMiddleware>();

    app.UseDefaultFiles(); // load index.html as default page
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseOrchardCore();
}
```

**EDIT**
I did not recognize that there are specific routes that the API should answer at. If you want to run the MVC request pipeline on only some specific routes, you could override the path for all other routes:

```cs
app.UseWhen(ctx => !ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && !ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/admin"), builder =>
    {
        builder.UseMiddleware<ReturnDefaultMiddleware>();
    });
```

This will append the middleware to all request that do not start with path /admin or /api.
The middleware will be as simple as this:

```cs
public class ReturnDefaultMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public ReturnDefaultMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Rewrite the request to request index.html
        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
        // Rerun the request pipeline
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Note that relative links in your index.html will not work with this solution. You could consider to override the path for specific file endings or paths inside the middleware as well.

Comment: and what when happens a real 404? I will lost it, redirecting to "static" files (which is not so good).

Comment: If a matching route was found, `context.Response.HasStarted` will be true so the fallback will not be used. The check was wrong and I corrected it in my edit.

Comment: Thinking about it makes me come to the result that the check for `context.Response.HasStarted` is enough to see if there was a matching route.

Comment: Tried your code, but doesn't work. It just return the 404

Comment: See my edit on the answer. If you work with fixed routes inside your mvc, you can use `UseWhen` to override the path based on actual path prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in a Blazor WebAssembly Hosted application with authentication enabled.
In my situation when I was calling `/api/{controller}` in Postman I was receiving html instead of json.

I fixed this by adding:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        ...
        endpoints.Map("api/{**slug}", HandleApiFallback);
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("{**slug}", "index.html");
    });


    private Task HandleApiFallback(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

I think it can be adapted for you situation also.

Another way that can work is:

```
        // In production, the Vue files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });




        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                endpoints.MapToVueCliProxy(
                    "{*path}",
                    new SpaOptions { SourcePath = "ClientApp" },
                    npmScript: "serve",
                    regex: "Compiled successfully");
            }

            // Add MapRazorPages if the app uses Razor Pages. Since Endpoint Routing includes support for many frameworks, adding Razor Pages is now opt -in.
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
        });
```

Your Vue app should be inside a directory named "ClientApp". Please have a look on this [sample](https://github.com/SoftwareAteliers/asp-net-core-vue-starter).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in ASP. NET 6 with the build of my react app, but i just add this funcion and it solved my problem (uses the controllers, if not found them, uses the navigation of my react app, even the routes that does not exist enter to my 404 custom page in react).

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>  
{  
    await next();  
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))  
    {  
        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";  
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;  
        await next();  
    }  
});
```

I'm thinking that you already used this methods, if not, I used them AFTER the function for routing

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```